# __init__, inheritance and variadic parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, variadic-functions

I'd like to subclass an existing **scons** class (named `SConsEnvironment`) which has the following `__init__` prototype:

```
 def __init__(self,
                 platform=None,
                 tools=None,
                 toolpath=None,
                 variables=None,
                 parse_flags = None,
                 **kw):
```

In my own class `Environment`, which derives from `SConsEnvironment`, I tried to do:

```
def __init__(self,
             platform=None,
             tools=None,
             toolpath=None,
             variables=None,
             parse_flags = None,
             **kw):

    if ('ENV' not in kw):
        kw['ENV'] = os.environ.copy()

    super(EIDEnvironment, self).__init__(
            platform,
            tools,
            toolpath,
            variables,
            parse_flags,
            kw) //Error here
```

Python complains:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given):
```

Unless I don't know how to count anymore, it seems that both `__init__` functions take 7 arguments. I'm sure there is a good reason for this not to work, but what is it and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `super(EIDEnvironment, self).__init__(...)` call, change `kw` to `**kw`. As the code is currently written, you're passing a dictionary containing the keyword args, but not actually passing them as keyword args.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to unpack *kw* otherwise you pass it as a dictionary:

```
super(EIDEnvironment, self).__init__(
            platform,
            tools,
            toolpath,
            variables,
            parse_flags,
            **kw)
```